# How to fix your login asp.net mvc to load the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[image]

My Login page is failing to launch each time. The error is

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.

I rechecked the following files RouteConfig.cs and did map the routes as following including controller with action method. The question is now, how can this page not load? The register page does load and checked just now.

```
// Controller class
        // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "";
            TempData["LoginMessage"] = "";
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);

            }

            var emailExist = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if(emailExist != null)
            {
                if(emailExist.EmailConfirmed == false)
                {
                    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(emailExist.Id);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = emailExist.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(emailExist.Id, "Confirm your account", ConfirmAccountMailBody(callbackUrl));

                    TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Email id is not verified. Please check your email and verify account !!!";
                    ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction = "ShowErrorPopup();";
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Email is not registered !!!";
                ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction = "ShowErrorPopup();";
                return View(model);
            }

            var loggedinUser = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            if(loggedinUser !=null)
            {
                await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(loggedinUser.Id);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Email or Password is Incorrect";
                    ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction = "ShowErrorPopup();";
                    return View(model);
            }
        }

// Route-config
   // Route to Login.
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Login",
               url: "login/",
               defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );

// Index.cshtml
@using eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
}


<div class="login-box">
    <div class="login-logo">
        <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Login")"><b>eNtsa</b> Registration</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-logo -->
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body login-card-body">
            <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", type = "email", placeholder = "Email", autofocus = "autofocus", required = "required" })
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", type = "password", placeholder = "Password" })
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <div class="icheck-primary">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @type = "checkbox", id = "remember" })
                            <label for="remember">
                                Remember Me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
            }

            <div class="social-auth-links text-center mb-3">
                <section id="socialLoginForm">
                    @*@Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })*@
                </section>
            </div>
            <!-- /.social-auth-links -->

            <p class="mb-1">
                <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ForgotPasswd")">Forgot your password?</a>
            </p>
            <p class="mb-0">
                <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Register")" class="text-center">Register a new membership</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.login-card-body -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-danger" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content bg-danger">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Authentication Failed !</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @TempData["ErrorMessage"]
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowErrorPopup() {
        $("#modal-danger").modal();
    }
</script>
@if (ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
            @Html.Raw(ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction)
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Does it hit the controller method `Index`?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, why not to do this?

```
 routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Login",
               url: "Account/Index",
               defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

Comment: sorry, try to remove first /

Comment: And why u dont want to use default routing

routes.MapRoute("Default",
                    "{controller}/{action}/",
                    new
                    {
                        controller = "Home",
                        action = "Index",
                    }
                );

Comment: @Makrs let me busy with something quick, let you know including here as to how did i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your route has Index page but you didnot make any Index(HTTP GET) page. That's why this error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

```
RouteConfig.cs

    /*routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Login",
                url: "login/",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            */
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Login",
               url: "login/",
               defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

2. Deleted the Login.cshtml that came with the file. NB. This is MVC.ASP.NET with Individual Account User
3. Each time the page gets loaded, it fetch the maping route and hit the controller. Its working now.